# c# dropdown select record

Tags: c#, database, combobox, lookup

I am very familiar with c# but not so much with building windows database apps.  I am trying to build a form with a drop down populated with the key values for each row in the table and use the drop down to select the row.  I have done this several times in Access and it sets up automatically.  I have found examples of the code required to setup the drop down, but I was wondering if there was a simple way to do it with the data set.  Setting up the binding navigator sets up all the code for the form in the background files.  Is there a tool that will auto set this up or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by too broad?  I would like to use a drop down control to navigate to specific records in an edit form and I am looking for suggestions on the correct method.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx